# Occasional Blank (black, but on) Screen - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (x86 64-bit)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, graphics-card, blank-screen

I'm not a completely new user of Ubuntu/Linux, but I'm still by far a novice.

I also am not 100% certain what all information is needed (and/or how to get it), so please let me know what I'm missing.

My problem is that occasionally, when booting, after GRUB comes up, it will flash a few times and go to a blank/black screen. The display is clearly on and lit, but it shows nothing. No cursor, nothing. It *will* play the startup sound, but I have to do a hard shutdown and turn it completely back on to be able to log in.

I find it odd because I have a much older laptop (a Fujitsu Lifebook) that has many other problems, but I never have this problem.

I also have taken note that the standard startup process that Ubuntu is apparently going through is not displayed for me. It's my understanding that there is a splash screen that is displayed during boot - I never see it. I consistently, after grub, see a black screen that flashes. Eventually, it will typically load to a blank screen with cursor and then the login screen. Other times, it's the blank black screen that's on.

I've not seen this happen after I've returned from sleep mode. It only seems to happen when I am starting up.

I have a dual-boot with Windows 10, but I am not sure it has any relevance. Also, I apologize for the length but I don't know how to put all the LSHW results into their own separate scrolling window within this post.

- Kernel: 3.16.0-46 generic (but it's been happening since I first
  installed - over a month ago)
- Processor: AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD
  Radeon R5 Graphics x 4
- Memory: 4.7 GB
- Hard Drive: 191.6 GB
- Graphics Card: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. (AMD/ATI) Mullins [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics]

LSHW Results:

```
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=IDEAPAD sku=LENOVO_MT_80E3_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo G50-45 uuid=81D08D9D-AB5C-11E4-A961-68F7287EB96A
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Lancer 5B2
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: 31900058 WIN
       serial: PF07A2FU
       slot: Base Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: A2CN27WW(V1.09)
          date: 12/12/2014
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics
          serial: NotSupport
          slot: Socket FT3b
          size: 1600MHz
          capacity: 2GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb perfctr_l2 arat cpb xsaveopt hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold vmmcall bmi1 cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 20
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 6GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: HMT451S6AFR8A-PB
             vendor: Hynix
             physical id: 0
             serial: 0262F9CC
             slot: DIMM 0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: HMT425S6AFR6A-PB
             vendor: Hynix
             physical id: 1
             serial: 102892A8
             slot: DIMM 1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Mullins [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
             resources: irq:81 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0c00000-f0c3ffff memory:f0800000-f081ffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:84 memory:f0c60000-f0c63fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:72 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f0b00000-f0bfffff ioport:f0d00000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 00
                serial: 2c:33:7a:4c:04:e1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.16.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:32 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0b00000-f0b03fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:73 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f0a00000-f0afffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 10
                serial: 68:f7:28:7e:b9:6a
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:80 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0a04000-f0a04fff memory:f0a00000-f0a03fff
        *-generic:0
             description: Encryption controller
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msix ht pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=AMD Cryptographic Coprocessor latency=0
             resources: irq:0 memory:f0c40000-f0c5ffff memory:f0900000-f09fffff memory:f0c70000-f0c70fff memory:f0c6a000-f0c6bfff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB XHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 10
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
             version: 11
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f0c68000-f0c69fff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage pm msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:79 ioport:4118(size=8) ioport:4124(size=4) ioport:4110(size=8) ioport:4120(size=4) ioport:4100(size=16) memory:f0c6f000-f0c6f3ff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f0c6e000-f0c6e0ff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f0c6d000-f0c6d0ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: FCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 42
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: latency=0
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: FCH Azalia Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:85 memory:f0c64000-f0c67fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: FCH LPC Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-generic:1
             description: SD Host controller
             product: FCH SD Flash Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.7
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=39
             resources: irq:16 memory:f0c6c000-f0c6c0ff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST500LT012-1DG14
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: LVM1
             serial: W3PE8ZA2
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=65589a8d-f5a9-41c7-ae1b-f1ddb5a8714e sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 1c9d-9540
                size: 998MiB
                capacity: 999MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-07-23 16:59:30 filesystem=ntfs label=WINRE_DRV modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: a49e-34c6
                size: 247MiB
                capacity: 259MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI system partition state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: FAT32
                serial: 2e94-b703
                size: 984MiB
                capacity: 999MiB
                capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=Basic data partition
           *-volume:3
                description: reserved partition
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                serial: d37ec3e1-7f48-457b-ace7-b364cb4a24f5
                capacity: 127MiB
                capabilities: nofs
                configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
           *-volume:4
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 3.1
                serial: 4a67e70f-0000-1e45-a17b-7444acec0908
                size: 233GiB
                capacity: 233GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-07-23 16:59:36 filesystem=ntfs label=Windows8_OS name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:5
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                version: 3.1
                serial: 2253c432-6059-794f-b923-223418077735
                size: 24GiB
                capacity: 24GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-02-05 15:25:36 filesystem=ntfs label=LENOVO modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:6
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 7
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,7
                logical name: /dev/sda7
                version: 3.1
                serial: 549a-5b45
                size: 14GiB
                capacity: 14GiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-02-05 14:53:47 filesystem=ntfs label=PBR_DRV modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:7
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 8
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,8
                logical name: /dev/sda8
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 17d488e7-1c45-4134-a585-d37573e76c0e
                size: 185GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2015-08-09 18:47:53 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2015-08-30 16:58:14 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2015-08-30 16:58:14 state=mounted
           *-volume:8
                description: swap partition
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 9
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,9
                logical name: /dev/sda9
                serial: c7c4d5be-b08c-402b-8808-87d3433d647a
                capacity: 5080MiB
                capabilities: nofs
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GUC0N
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: T.02
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

In case it isn't mentioned in there, I am on a Lenovo G50-45. It's fine when I boot Windows, *usually fine* when I boot Ubuntu.

**UPDATE 9-2-2015**

Results of running "ubuntu-devices drivers" in Terminal:

```
heather@Heather-Lenovo-Ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0 ==
vendor   : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
modalias : pci:v00001002d00009851sv000017AAsd00003801bc03sc00i00
driver   : fglrx - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-ati - distro free builtin recommended
driver   : fglrx-updates - distro non-free
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the graphics card driver. Open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

The output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` will show a list of graphics card drivers from the Ubuntu repositories that are compatible with your laptop. I would expect that *fglrx* would be the right proprietary graphics card driver to install for a Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics.

The built-in xserver-xorg-video-ati graphics card driver is listed as recommended because it is already installed in Ubuntu 14.04 by default. If you install the fglrx proprietary graphics card driver, Ubuntu will use fglrx without uninstalling xserver-xorg-video-ati, so that you can still boot with the open source xserver-xorg-video-ati graphics card driver in case you have a problem booting with fglrx.

To install fglrx and the Catalyst Control Center for the AMD Radeon graphics accelerator (*fglrx-amdcccle*), open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle  
sudo reboot
```

fglrx is no longer supported in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. In Ubuntu 16.04 and later AMD graphics processors use the built-in open source AMD graphics driver by default. Alternatively you can download the latest stable version of the proprietary AMD graphics driver from the [official AMD website](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

Comment: Thank you. I ran that and edited my original question with the results.

I read, just now, that fglrx is a proprietary ATI driver, yet the results recommend the xorg driver. Should I install the xorg driver instead? Is it only recommending it because it's open source?

Comment: I edited my answer with a reply to your comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I installed the fglrx driver and I have restarted several times and I've not seen the blank screen again, and I now see the purple screen and the splash screen as I'm booting up, so everything looks to have worked.